# 2 types of text on the same line

Tags: html, css

It's actually quit simple and it seems so stupid that I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried float:left, display:inline-block, width and heights, margin and padding. Nothing seems to work. Until last night, now the problem is how do I get the "(Frequently Asked Questions)" to move away from "FAQ"? I've tried margin-right and even padding-right

HTML:

```
<div id="faq-text">
<h2 class="h2-faq">FAQ<p class="faq-ptag">(Frequently Asked Questions)</p>
</h2>
```

CSS:

```
#faq-text{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.faq-ptag{
    font-size:20px;
    width:300px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.h2-faq{
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Try `margin-left:10px` on `.faq-ptag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following css to set (Frequently Asked Questions) in next line.

```
#faq-text{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.faq-ptag{
    font-size:20px;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.h2-faq{
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

and use following code to create some gap b/w FAQ and (Frequently Asked Questions)

```
#faq-text{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.faq-ptag{
    font-size:20px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
}

.h2-faq{
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove fixed width from this class  `.faq-ptag`: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwmxvny8/2/)**

This demo will align `Frequently Asked Questions` text to right side

```
.faq-ptag{
 font-size:20px;
 width:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 }
```

**Update**: Here you can give `margin-left` value according to your requirement: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwmxvny8/3/)**

CSS:

```
.faq-ptag {
    font-size:20px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin-left` on `.faq-ptag` works.

```
  .faq-ptag{
    font-size:20px;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
```

If you were adding margin or padding on `.h2-faq` it wont work.
You could make `.h2-faq {display:inline-block}` then move `.faq-ptag` out of it and add `margin-right` on `.h2-faq`.

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvYgjN).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="faq-text">
<span class="h2-faq">FAQ</span>
<span class="faq-ptag">(Frequently Asked Questions)</span></div>
```

> in css as below edit :

```
.faq-ptag{
font-size:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could/should try out positioning absolute/relative instead:

```css
#faq-text {
  position: relative;
}
.h2-faq {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.faq-ptag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="faq-text">
  <h2 class="h2-faq">FAQ</h2>
  <p class="faq-ptag">(Frequently Asked Questions)</p>
</div>
```